# can xpath project 2+ fields?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, projection

There is a webpage consisting of anchor elements. I want to select the *text* and the attribute *href* values from all of anchor elements. I am using scrapy's xpath engine to do the same. So I have tried the follows without much success:

```
response.xpath('//a[position()>1]/(text()|@href)').extract()
response.xpath('//a[position()>1]/text()/@href').extract()
```

But these errors out.

Is this possible in a xpath in the first place?

Ps: its probably not correct to say scrapy's xpath engine - I think its lxml python package.

Comment: How should the result be structured? Please give an example of source and the corresponding result.

Comment: Really I was hoping the xpath engine would automatically figure that one out...hence the doubt if such an operation was possible in the first place...But I was expecting some sort of a JSON-like (or a dict) document. with text and href as fields for each item.

Comment: XPath is just a language to navigate through XML, it can't do things like this. That's what is your task, to compose the pieces extracted using XPath together in a form you need. Simplest solution might be to extract the anchor using `anchor = response.xpath('//a[position()>1]')` and then `yield {'text': anchor.xpath('./text()'), 'link': anchor.xpath('./@href')}`.

Comment: Don't tell us that something "errors out". Tell us what the error message is.

Comment: The XPath expressions are fine: they return a set of nodes (attribute and text nodes) in the source document. The question is what the (Scrapy?) extract() function does with such a node-set.